# Common table expression defining a function in a cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor, common-table-expression

Does somebody know if it is possible to use the a common table expression that defines a local function inside a PL/SQL cursor?

For example this code produce an error for me:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR LV_CUR IS
  WITH  function fct2(x number) return number is 
    begin
     return 2*x;
    end;
   TEMP_AV AS
    (
      SELECT
        fct2(LEVEL)
      FROM
       DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10
    )
SELECT
  *
FROM
  TEMP_AV;
BEGIN
  FOR I IN LV_CUR
  LOOP
    NULL;
    dbms_output.put_line(i.level);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

The error is :

> ORA-06550: Ligne 3, colonne 18 :
>   PL/SQL: ORA-00905: mot-clé absent
>   ORA-06550: Ligne 3, colonne 3 :
>   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   ORA-06550: Ligne 6, colonne 5 :
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:
>      begin function pragma procedure subtype type 
>       current cursor delete
>      exists prior

I am able to execute the query (with the common table expression including a function definition) outside PL/SQL.

Comment: I think the problem is `with function`. try creating the function before creating the cursor.

Comment: I tried to create it inside the declare bloc, but it seems that I can only do it as the last declared object, so I can't use it in the cursor ..

Comment: I mean if you declare the function outside of pl/sql

Comment: All right, but that's what I would like to avoid !

Comment: ok, then maybe you should explain why you need that requirement so we understand the problem a little better. But my approach is try to solve the problem first. Once you have a working solution then you can ask. I already did A. But I try to do B and doesn't work. I can see kfinity say `WITH` is ok maybe the problem is `WITH function`. So if you create the function outside and kfinity solutions works we can continue from there.

Comment: Why I need this answer doesn't matter. I just want to know if it's possible. I don't want to create a new function in the database.

Comment: Check [HERE](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1#functions)    **Functions in the WITH Clause**

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza : Thank you, that seem to be the most complete answer till now.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say, based on the text looks like you cant do what you want. So you have to create the function outside first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. [The 12.1 docs for the CURSOR statement](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/explicit_cursor.htm#GUID-38C5DBA3-9DEC-4AF2-9B5E-7B721D11A77C__CJAIACGI) explicitly say:

> **Restriction on select_statement**
>
> This select_statement cannot have a WITH clause.

This docs are wrong in this case, since you *can* have a WITH clause, it apparently just can't have the new 12c PL/SQL declarations in it. This block works fine, for example.

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR LV_CUR IS
  WITH  
   TEMP_AV AS
    (
      SELECT
        level
      FROM
       DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10
    )
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    TEMP_AV;
BEGIN
  FOR I IN LV_CUR
  LOOP
    NULL;
    dbms_output.put_line(i.level);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: In fact, I already know that the code you gave was working ... I wonder if I should accept your answer, since the response to my question seems to be no (and not yes and no) ... but you're right and the conclusion about the code I gave .. and the link in the commentary from Juan Carlos Oropez is a little bit more complete ..